# Ajax Call Sequence in a function

Tags: javascript

I have a little question. say i have a js function

```
$(function() {
 $(".button").click(function(){ 
 var id=$(this).attr('id');
 var dataString = 'id='+ id ;
 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "download_number.php",
   data: dataString,
   cache: false,
   success: function(html)
   {
     $("#div_"+id).html(html);
   }  });
   window.open('File_download.php?file_id='+id, '_blank' );
  });
```

as you can see `window.open` call is after $.ajax call

Does it guaratee that $.ajax call will get executed every time before the page reloads and if no then

shouldn't we declare `window.open` in success function?

In my opinion when there is slow response from server the page will reload first and it may happen that `$.ajax` call will be interrupted by `window.open` function

but i get a downvote for the same reason here stackoverflow.com/questions/12908138/how-to-get-the-id-or-name-of-related-file/

And Thanks for making my belief stronger

Comment: "shouldn't we declare window.open in success function?" - Yes, you should! What makes you think otherwise?

Comment: or you should use $.ajax as a deferred and chain a .done() with your open function (if you want the open to be called no matter what) see: http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/ About the rest, your assumptions are correct.

Comment: @m90 because sir i gave the same answer here stackoverflow.com/questions/12908138/how-to-get-the-id-or-name-of-related-file/ and i get a downvote

Comment: @SamueleMattiuzzo: Why? The success callback works good as well.

Comment: I don't understand why you are asking this question, you clearly know the answer, as demonstrated in the question you linked.

Comment: @Bergi if it's not succes and you still want to go to that download.php page? i consider the .done() method some sort of "finally" after a try catch

Comment: @wisdom all this fuss is just for a downvote in another post and you absolutely want to prove you're right?

Comment: @Jivings, because the question i linked, the person was so consistent that i had no choice but to look if i am wrong or not?

Comment: @SamueleMattiuzzo, i want to absolutely sure for the next time if this question raises again.

Comment: @SamueleMattiuzzo: No, `done()` is like `onSuccess`. The catch-all method for Deferreds would be [`always`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.always/) - although I'm quite sure you don't want to download anything when the upload failed

Comment: @Bergi my bad then! Well it depends what that download page does, if it's just starting a download (in this case i don't want to download it) or maybe a complete page (displays success/failure message etc) and in this case, an always() statement would be correct i guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, the `window.open` function will always (!) be called before the `success` callback function given to the `ajax` call. Ajax traffic is always asynchronous, whereas the `window.open` function resides in the synchronous JS `<script>` tag.

Since JavaScript is single-threaded, all synchronous statements will always be executed before any asynchronous functionality like `ajax setTimeout animate` etc.

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "download_number.php",
   data: dataString,
   cache: false,
   success: function(html) { // asynchronous functionality
     $("#div_"+id).html(html);
   }  
}); 
// within synchronous script statements
window.open('File_download.php', '_blank' );
```

Comment: thats what i think but what this person does not see  stackoverflow.com/questions/12908138/how-to-get-the-id-or-name-of-related-file/ and i get a downvote

Comment: @wisdom: Then ignore the troll - you can't force him to learn :-)

Comment: @Bergi first of all I am her not him,secondly see my site you can search forexample james and see that it is working  I have done it myself http://parsa-web.goodluckwith.us/voting.php and the window.open is after success

Comment: @wisdom when you don't getthe question,don't say something else to people and don't claim that you are so expert and blah blah blah

Comment: @nikparsa: Sorry, I'm getting a [virus warning](http://swi1-0.p.link.sophos.com/t/de/Mal/HTMLGen-A) for that page

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Ajax is asynchronous so you will open that window right after you started the XHR process. To download the processed data, open the new window from the success callback. Yet I'm not sure what you mean by "*before the page reloads*" - there is no code which does that.

Also I don't know how your server behaves, the `file_download.php` seems to be independent from your ajax call. Shouldn't you pass the `download_number` you received via ajax in there?